# Remove last character from string in asp.net not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, replace

I want to remove `,` from the string which I get it as while debugging is

`27/1, 106/2,`

**Note** after`,` there is space too.

So. I tried with below code

```
if (txt712.Text != "")
        {
           string strText = txt712.Text;

           strText = strText.Remove(strText.Length - 2, 1);
           xw.WriteElementString("SURVEY_AREA_7_12", strText);
        }
```

But while saving it is giving me error as

> Invalid number

Comment: do you want to remove all the ", " or only the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code..

```
var str = "127/10,";
var TrimedStr= str.substring(0, str.length-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Trim()`  it will remove the white space from the string and `Regex.Replace` for replacing `,`

```
            if (txt712.Text != "")
            {
                string strText = txt712.Text;
                strText = Regex.Replace(strText.Trim(),",", "");   
                xw.WriteElementString(strText);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

strText = strText.Trim().replace(',','');

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove only the last one

```
 str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
```

If you want to remove all the "," and the last space

```
    str = str.Trim().Replace(",", "");
```

In your code I am not sure about what `xw.WriteElementString` does. 
So I think there's some other logical errors and `xw.WriteElementString` isn't accepting the string value.